# Images not displaying with asp.net repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater

I am trying to display pictures from folder Images with a repeater,but the probelm pictures can not display i don't know why .

```html
 <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 356px; overflow: hidden;">

                                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RepaterImages">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div  runat="server" data-p="144.50">
                                            
                                          <img  id="Image" runat="server" data-u="image" style="Width:120px;" src='<%#Container.DataItem %>'/>                                          

                                        </div>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

    var path = Server.MapPath("ProjectsImages/ ");

    var images = Directory.GetFiles(path,id+"*");

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    foreach (var img in images)
    {

        list.Add(img);

    }
    RepaterImages.DataSource = images;
    RepaterImages.DataBind();
 }
```

Comment: Please post the **rendered HTML** of your page.

Comment: Change `<%#Container.DataItem %>` into `<%# Eval("columnName") %>`

Comment: @VDWWD i retrieve the images from folder not database table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is, you are using physical path of the image. You will have to provide relative path to repeater. Change your code as below, it should work I think:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                string relativePath = "/ProjectsImages/";
                var path = Server.MapPath(relativePath);
                var images = Directory.GetFiles(path, id + "*").Select(x =>
                {
                    var arrPath = x.Split('\\');
                    string imgName = arrPath[arrPath.Length - 1];
                    return relativePath + imgName;
                });
                RepaterImages.DataSource = images;
                RepaterImages.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the Postback property. Please use the code below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

        var path = Server.MapPath("ProjectsImages/ ");

        var images = Directory.GetFiles(path,id+"*");

        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

        foreach (var img in images)
        {

           list.Add(img);

       }
       RepaterImages.DataSource = list;
       RepaterImages.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this not working but i think this problem form paths but i am not sure

Comment: previously the code was not datasource used images attribute instead of arrayList. Updated the code check now